# algebraic independence in Pfaffian

Tags: linear-algebra, pfaffian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $G=(g_{ij})$ be a skew-symmetric matrix with $g_{ij}\in R$. Then if $C$ is an $n\times n$-matrix in $R$, then $\rm{Pf}$$(C^{\top}GC)$ = $\rm{det}$$(C)$$\rm{Pf}$$(G)$.

Several proofs of the statement over $\mathbb{Z}$ establish $\rm{Pf}$$(U^{\top}TU)$ = $\pm\rm{det}$$(U)$$\rm{Pf}$$(T)$ using $\rm{det}$$(G)=\rm{Pf}$$(G)^2$, take off the negative sign by replacing $U$ with identity, and finally replace $U$ with $C$ and $T$ with $G$. But in doing so, there's the assumption that $n\times n$ coefficients $u_{ij}$ be **algebraically independent** --- why is this assumption crucial here?

Comment: The algebraic independence is what ensures that you can substitute the identity matrix for $U$ (and end up with the same $\pm$ sign as originally).

Comment: @darijgrinberg could you please elaborate on that? Given the definition that "no nontrivial algebraic equation in $u_{ij}$" do you mean that $n$ 1's and $(n\times n - n)$ 0's are so? But eventually we'll replace $U$ with any $C$ in $R$ --- I think I must have missed something

Comment: I'm afraid I won't get around to elaborating on anything in the next days, but here are two relevant notes by Keith Conrad: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/univid.pdf and https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/univid2.pdf . Essentially, if you don't use indeterminates for the entries of $U$, but use a specific matrix $U$ instead, then there is no guarantee that different matrices $U$ won't have different values of the $\pm$ sign.

Comment: @darijgrinberg can I roughly say that algebraic independence of $U$ licenses substituting in **any** $C$ (including those with algebraically dependent $c_{ij}$), whereas any nontrivial relation among its entries allows only substitution of matrices imposing the same? (seems to be a concept similar to "freeness" of structures). Thank you for sharing those notes!!

Comment: Yes, precisely. This is the universal property of the polynomial ring in action.